# Почему не срабатывает console.log?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
(async () => {
    await download_maps(maps_arr);
    console.log(repack())
})();



function repack(){
    return "test"
}

function download_maps(maps_arr){
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        maps_arr.forEach(function(item, index, array) {
            let map_arr = item.split(": ")
            let file = fs.createWriteStream(`...`);
            let request = https.get(`...`, function(response) {
                response.pipe(file);
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Работа приложения завершается после завершения работы download_maps() без вывода сообщения в консоль.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`await` ждет пока выполнится promise возвращаемый функцией `download_maps`, но так как внутри этой функции нигде не вызывается `resolve` переводящий promise в состояние *готово* - `await` будет ждать его бесконечно.

Поэтому не будет перехода к следующей строке.

Comment: А как нужно использовать async, await и promise в функции 'download_maps', чтобы следующая загрузка выполнялась после завершения прошлой?
UPD: Я удалил вторую часть вопроса, т.к понял что забыл написать console.log

Comment: @Diavolo, честно говоря не совсем понял что код должен делать `await` надо использовать с Promise, если создаешь его сам с помощью конструктора надо вызвать resolve, чтобы он завершился